# Как пропарсить xml-файл?

Tags: c#, xml, парсер, xmlparser

Доброго времени суток, господа! Очень нужна ваша помощь, будьте добры, помогите пропарсить xml..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <users>
    <user name="Bill Gates" group="programmers">
    <company>Microsoft</company>
    <age>48</age>
  </user>
  <user name="Larry Page" group="programmers">
    <company>Google</company>
    <age>42</age>
  </user>
  <user name="Edward Norton" single="actor">
    <company>NewLineCinema</company>
    <age>40</age>
  </user>
 </users>
```

Если в теге user атрибут group **существует**, то считываем все блоки где group=programmers. А если, его нет, но при этом существует элемент single, то считываем только этот блок. Всем заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если есть сингл - то запись одна (во-первых, определить это), затем считать все атрибуты (в оригинале атрибутов намного больше, эта упрощенная модель). Если есть груп, то записи объединяются в одно целое, и также считываются их атрибуты.

Comment: С обработкой, мне необходимо нужные данные из него достать, а не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с применением XPath запросов и LINQ for XML.

Вот пример XPath. Для начала Вам нужно подготовить Ваш XML, для этого можно использовать объекты Stream, передать в конструктор URI или использовать самый простой XMLReader. В данном случае для полноты использован MemoryStream, для остальных смотрите [описание XDocument.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
          <users>
            <user name=""Bill Gates"" group=""programmers"">
            <company>Microsoft</company>
            <age>48</age>
          </user>
          <user name=""Larry Page"" group=""programmers"">
            <company>Google</company>
            <age>42</age>
          </user>
          <user name=""Edward Norton"" single=""actor"">
            <company>NewLineCinema</company>
            <age>40</age>
          </user>
         </users>
        ";
        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);
```

После того, как документ загружен, можно легко считывать данные с помощью XPath запросов. Они могут быть достаточно гибкими и сложными, позволяя обрабатывать одной строкой множество условий. Из минусов, придется изучить XPath.

```
        var programmers = xdoc.Document.XPathSelectElements(@"./users/user[@group=""programmers""]");
        var single = xdoc.Document.XPathSelectElements(@"./users/user[@single]");
        var result = programmers.Count() > 0 ? programmers : single;
```

UPD: пример вывода на консоль данных

```
        foreach (var res in result) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(res.Element("company").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(res.Element("age").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(res.Attribute("name") != null ? res.Attribute("name").Value : "");
            Console.WriteLine(res.Attribute("group") != null ? res.Attribute("group").Value : "");
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только..а как получить значение single и programmers? Сейчас они выводят C#-код

Comment: @YuriGo, programmers это значение анттрибута, а single это атрибут! какие вы хотите получить значения от них ?

Comment: @YuriGo, они возвращают коллекцию [элементов XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) из `User`, в документации можно посмотреть, как с ней работать. Возможные варианты, в цикле `foreach(var res in result)` выводить: `res.Element("company").Value`, `res.Element("age").Value`,  `res.Attribute("group") != null ? res.Attribute("group").Value : " "` и т.д. и т.п..

Answer (score 1):

исходя из того что я понял в вашем вопросе можно сделать так :

```
        //Читаем документ
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("xml.xml");
        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        //создаем запросы xpath
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(@"/users/user[@group=""programmers""]");
        var programmers = iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>().ToList();

        iterator = nav.Select(@"/users/user[@single=""actor""]");
        var single = iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>().ToList();


        var result = programmers.Any() ? programmers : single;

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Найден элемент :\n {0}", item.InnerXml));

        }
```

[Примеры XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256086(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: открыл для себя XPath, спасибо :)
Единственное, я почему-то понял так, что если есть Single, то ТОЛЬКО его нужно считать, а так то можно было и Doc'ом проще сделать.

Comment: @xSx, а ну может быть, если есть Single, то только его нужно считать, тогда конечно нужно изменить запрос XPATH, возможно я не правильно понял вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться Linq to XML.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elementsProgrammers = xUsersParticipants
                  .Element("users")
                    .Elements("user")
                     .Where(e => ((string)e.Attribute("group")) =="programmers").Select(i => i);
    if(elementsProgrammers.Count() == 0)
      {             
        elementsProgrammers = xUsersParticipants
                 .Element("users")
                      .Elements("user")
                        .Where(e => ((string)e.Attribute("group"))=="single")
                          .Select(i => i);
      }
    foreach(XElement element in elementsProgrammers )
    {
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Но, ответ уже найден :)

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб(в тупую :D), можно так

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>  <users>    <user name=\"Bill Gates\" group=\"programmers\">    <company>Microsoft</company>    <age>48</age>  </user>  <user name=\"Larry Page\" group=\"programmers\">    <company>Google</company>    <age>42</age>  </user>  <user name=\"Edward Norton\" single=\"actor\">    <company>NewLineCinema</company>    <age>40</age>  </user> </users>");
        bool ProgIn = false;
        foreach (XmlNode noda in doc.DocumentElement)
        {

            if (noda.LocalName == "user")
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute atr in noda.Attributes)
                    if (atr.Value == "programmers")
                    {
                        ProgIn = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Считываем везде где программерс");
                    }
                foreach (XmlAttribute atr in noda.Attributes)
                    if (!ProgIn)
                        if (atr.Name == "single")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Считываем только сингл");
                            return;
                        }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: возьмите, как пример, как взять нужные ноды. Можно точно сделать без двойного цикла, пока, что-то я втупил жутко, поэтому предлагаю самим помучиться)

Comment: Благодарю! Ну а если не в тупую?) Есть ли какие-нибудь более изящные варианты :)